# Getting a list of Installed Applications on a computer where the Application is not listed SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall

Tags: powershell

I have a question about windows Powershell. I'm looking for a few ideas on how to find installed applications on a computer that aren't found in the uninstall register.

I've already incorporated this script http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-programs.html into my code but there are still applications that have been manually placed into the computer that the script can't pick up

My current idea is to check to see if the folder path exists, but this idea feels really inefficient and requires that I define the paths, meaning that I need to know ahead of time which programs are installed and where. This also means that I won't be able to find programs I don't know about.

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can try the WIN32_Product class in WMI, but if the installer doesn't write to the uninstall key then it probably isn't an MSI either. There is no enforced standard that provides a way to find the installed applications on a computer.

Comment: Thanks. I guess powering through really is the only solution then

Answer (score 0):

Try WMI:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter 'Name like "%SoftwareName%"'
```